# Regex: How to match only if there's something after /x in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using some regex on a site to redirect URLs like:
https://example.com/blog/myarticle to https://example.com/myarticle

I'm using the following redirect rule: /blog/(.*)$

The problem is, I don't want to redirect https://example.com/blog/ to https://example.com/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the actual rewriting rule you are referring to, not just a regular expression...

Comment: Maybe you just need to replace `(.*)` with `(.+)`. Or better `(.+)/?`, once you are at it...